# is it possible to use javascript,json from google contacts api v3?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api

can i use google contacts api v3 from javascript using json responses ? Google api v1, v2 could be used from javascript but they are currently depricated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use `alt=json` in your requests.

Source: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference

Comment: i see that i have to authenticate user first and get a token. but could not find how to use the token while querying. Am i going to use that in querystring ?

Comment: The authorization code should be placed in the authorization header of the call. Note that the authorization code is likely to have a limited lifetime. So check that it has not expired. If it has use the refresh code granted when the original authorization code was retrieved.

Comment: what about in a POST request (when adding a contact)? Is it possible to get JSON back?